# Using Sqlite3 in objective C How to Retrieve the number of rows in a result set

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

after a long search didn't succeed to get the required and easily understandable answer i am putting here a question….. 
so please help me out on it….

I just want know that how i can get the number of rows in a result set of a query in objective C using sqlite3.

as we just use the function of SQL Server in PHP.

```
$Query = "SELECT XXXX FROM XXX";
    $rstRow = Sql_Query($Query);

if (sqlsrv_num_rows($rstRow) > 0)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

what is alternate to this in sqlite3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count rows result set data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726502/count-rows-result-set-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite does not provide any function to get the number of rows return by a query. You can use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` to get total number rows.

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865615/getting-number-of-rows-from-sqlite-c-interface-in-objective-c)

Comment: is it suitable in my case… as i mentioned in my code example

Comment: Yes, it is possible in your case. Before executing the query `$Query = "SELECT XXXX FROM XXX";` execute the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXX` and get the count as an integer. then execute your query.